How to show battery percentage in taskbar in Windows 11?
Basically this question except for Windows 11.
Is there a [preferably native] way to show battery percentage in the taskbar without having to hover over or click the battery icon?


See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/battery-percentage-visualisation-on-taskbar-and/8c453e1b-dc4f-4998-8ad6-fbcd034c5737 :  there might be third-party tool, though those suggested have been removed.

There is an app on Microsoft store called "Battery Percentage - Pure Battery add-on"


Some explanation of how to use this tool to answer OPs question will make this a better answer. Also, a link to the app would help, as there can be loads of very similarly named apps.
